# Indexing in for and while loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am getting confused with an implementation of a loop in python while working with lists.

example: This implementation always throws list index out of range error because the list is different in each iteration and the len(intervals) always changes.

```
for i in range(len(intervals1)):
    for k in range(len(intervals2)):
        if intervals1[i] == intervals2[k]:
            count += 1
        else:
            intervals2.pop(k)
```

while the second implementation is

```
for i in intervals1:
    for k in intervals2:
        if i == k:
            count += 1
        else:
            intervals2.remove(k)
```

The second implementation works fine, but the first one always fails. I think that we can never work with an indexed approach while using for loops when we are removing/popping something from a list or modifying the number of elements in the list.

Could somebody please provide a workaround if we want to use indexed approach with the first implementation.

One implementation I have found is by using while loops, why does this work even though it is using an indexed based approach but for loops fail-

```
intervals1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

intervals2 = [4,5,6,7,8,9]

i=0
while i < len(intervals2):
    if intervals1[i] == intervals2[i]:
        count +=1

    else:
        intervals2.pop(i)
        intervals1.pop(i)

   print(intervals1)
print(intervals2)
```

Shouldn't this also fail as it is dynamically computing the length of the intervals. Maybe the reason is it isn't using a counter like for loop does, it can use that inside the loop though.

Could someone please explain this.

Thanks.

Comment: In the for loop, the count updates each iteration no matter what, you are changing the length of the list but not lowering the count to account for it having updated that iteration. Whereas in the while loop, you are only updating the count if you don't shorten the loop. The for loop should work if you put  k -= 1 in the else.

Comment: Is this the case with every language, like vectors in C++ too? where I think everything is dynamically resized and taken into account. Shouldn't length() automatically change, ideally?

Comment: Yes `pop` in a `for` loop is tricky.  Look at the list after the pop to see why.  A count down loop may work if you always remove elements after the current index.  Just pay close attention to the list and index.  Don't make assumptions.

Comment: Length is not re-evaluated on each iteration. It's been a while since I have dealt with C++ but i'm fairly sure it's the same there. Generally in most programming languages it's a bad idea to modify the length of an array as you are looping through it because it is easy to run into an index issue.

Comment: There is still a bug in your second second version, because you are modifying `intervals2` while you iterate over it.

Comment: What is the *actual problem you wish to solve* using either of these implementations? For example, for the given `intervals1` and `intervals2` in the last code block, what is the desired result?

Comment: I just want to see if these implementations work, no desired result. @juanpa.arrivillaga then how's the second implementation working? That's because there is no range object, right?

Comment: @gauravchandra it *happens* to work probably due to the nature of your inputs. But it won't work in general because it is still skipping indices internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pop-out elements, it is better to store the desired one in a new list popping out will cause this index error

```
intervals1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
count=0
intervals2 = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
res=[]
for i in range(len(intervals1)):
    for k in range(len(intervals2)):
        if intervals1[i] == intervals2[k]:
            count += 1
            res.append(intervals2[k])
```

Comment: Hmm, this is a good way but can the len() directly compute the length after each iteration or is it always fixed and decided at the first iteration?

Comment: I believe that it is set in the first step because if it supposed to calculate the length on each step, it requires more unnecessary calculation.

Comment: @gauravchandra no, you create a single `range` object and that is what is evaluated as the iterable part of the for-loop statement.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop  The difference between while and for is that in each iteration the condition won't be checked.  "Contrast the for statement with the ''while'' loop, used when a condition needs to be checked each iteration, or to repeat a block of code forever."